# What are the requirements for MAAS and OpenStack?

Tags: maas, openstack, cloud, landscape, openstack-autopilot

What is the minimum number of computers needed to install MAAS and OpenStack? Also, what are the hardware requirements for all nodes with OpenStack?

Answer (score 2):

For the OpenStack Autopilot in LDS 15.01, any 3 servers with IPMI will do, as long as they have 2 disks and at least one of them has 2 NICs (this isn't counting the LDS or MAAS machines, so 5 machines in total).

In the most general sense, three servers that are Ubuntu certified will be enough, or if not certified, a BMC supported by MAAS is required (IPMI being the most common choice).

That's for building your cloud. As far as to what your cloud can host, the resources - number of instances you can start, storage space available, etc, will depend on the specs of the hardware you use to build your cloud. You should have hardware appropriate to your intended usage.

Comment: I have total 5 servers and I went through installation setup with Autopilot. I got everything setup. I do have 3 nodes available but Apparently, you need at least 4 machines and 6 for HA??  It looks like there is a gap what they have on autopilot site and what actually it is required. Let me know if I am missing anything?