# Can I try Canonical Distribution of Ubuntu OpenStack with less than 7 machines?

Tags: maas, openstack, cloud, landscape, openstack-autopilot

Can I try Canonical Distribution of Ubuntu OpenStack with less than 7 machines?

Answer (score 2):

## Landscape Managed, Scaleable Cloud

See the following answer for the latest requirements:

- [Installation Requirements for Landscape Autopilot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/593754/what-are-the-requirements-for-maas-and-openstack)

TL;DR:

**5** -- One machine for MAAS, one machine for Landscape, and three for your cloud.

## Single Machine

There is a single machine option for getting a feel for things (using openstack-install), however it's not meant for a production workload.

You can follow the single machine option with these commands on Trusty and later:

```
sudo apt install openstack
sudo openstack-install
```