# Ubuntu Openstack installation tutorial video

Tags: maas, openstack, cloud, landscape, openstack-autopilot

Is there a video tutorial on how to install ubuntu openstack? The current tutorial doesn't say it all 7 servers need ubuntu installed on them.

Answer (score 2):

There is no installation tutorial video, but comprehensive instructions are here:

- http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack

It does not say that you need to install ubuntu on all machines because *you don't*: MAAS takes care of installing Ubuntu on those machines for you from bare metal.

The number of machines are not listed up front since it is variable depending on what your needs are and what services you want to deploy.  See the following question for more details:

- [Can I try Canonical Distribution of Ubuntu OpenStack with less than 7 machines?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/595770/)