# Ubuntu Cloud Minimum Servers

Tags: openstack, cloud, landscape, openstack-autopilot

Ubuntu Cloud [states that it requires 7 physical servers](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack). Why is this? Can an Ubuntu Cloud instance be done with less than 7?

Comment: source for the 7 min?

Comment: I would *guess* that those are needed for enough processing power? And the way it interfaces with the network and each other.

Comment: The source is [Source](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack) . I know that it can be done with less if you are doing openstack straight up, but it looks like maybe Ubuntu does not allow you to double up responsibilities on servers. Is this the case ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I try Canonical Distribution of Ubuntu OpenStack with less than 7 machines?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/595770/can-i-try-canonical-distribution-of-ubuntu-openstack-with-less-than-7-machines)

Answer (score 2):

I can give a partial answer.  The install procedure goes like this:

1. The first system becomes the MAAS server, as well as having an initial juju bootstrap environment used to start installing Landscape.  MAAS is used to provision the OS on the rest of the systems.
2. The second system becomes the Landscape system.  Once Landscape is up and running, you are directed to the OpenStack page in Landscape where you can specify what you want each remaining node's function to be.  The OpenStack page will refuse to proceed to the node picker if Landscape doesn't see 5 free systems registered with MAAS (and some with at least 2 hard drives).
3. The remaining 5 nodes become the OpenStack deployment.  People more knowledgeable than me can comment on how the 5 nodes are deployed. :)  I think there were 3 storage/compute nodes, a controller-type node that ran several services, and one other that I can't remember (network exit node?).

I was able to install on 6 nodes instead of 7 by setting up the initial MAAS server, then running Landscape inside of KVM on the MAAS server and registering the KVM instance in MAAS.  If you want more detail on how I did this, I can probably dig up my notes.  I tried this with more nodes as well, but it didn't work and I gave up as I had 6 nodes anyways.

If you want to install on just a few servers to try out OpenStack, there are other options available like DevStack or OSAD.  If you want to try out Ubuntu Cloud, you will need more systems.

Note: I ran into an issue where the hardware inventory kernel that MAAS uses to inventory the hardware wouldn't recognize my NIC.  A standard ubuntu server install would recognize it.  I had to buy some different NICs before Landscape would let me proceed.

Comment: It's 3 nodes for the cloud now with LDS 15.01 (your point "3"). If you change your answer accordingly above, I can promote it as the right one.

Comment: @andreas - What do you mean when you say LDS 15.01 ? - Google answered my question. Landscape

Comment: Flux, looks like a new version of Landscape: https://launchpad.net/~landscape/+archive/ubuntu/15.01

Comment: Yep: https://help.landscape.canonical.com/LDS/ReleaseNotes15.01